# How do I add context menus to HTML-editable forms?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, safari-extension

We develop extensions for Chrome, Firefox and Safari. We want to add context menus to our extensions that will show when right clicking on any form element which is HTML-editable.

Is it possible to define such a context menu?

I noticed that the editable context menu in Chrome works for every editable form element but we want to enable it only for form elements where the user can insert HTML. I also noticed that in many of these form elements, the base element has the attribute `[contenteditable="true"]` (or `[contenteditable=""]`).

Are there HTML-editable elements without this attribute? And if not, is it possible to target this attribute in our context menu?

We don't want the context menu to appear in regular text fields or text areas, only in those when the user can insert HTML. But if there is an element with `[contenteditable="false"]` with a parent with `[contenteditable="true"]`, we do want the context menu also for this element.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "form element which is HTML-editable"?  Any DOM element whose parent has the "contenteditable"property can be HTML-editable, it need not be a form.

Comment: @peterdotjs Any element which is HTML-editable, it doesn't have to be inside a `<form>`. I meant forms in forums, web mails etc. where the user can edit HTML. This include all the descendants of the HTML-editable element, even if the descendants themselves are not editable. We want to let the users add their signature to the parent element.

Comment: This firefox addon does exactly that: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8777224#file-bootstrap-js-L71 its a demo addon very simple

Comment: @Noitidart Is it possible to do it also in Chrome and Safari?

Comment: @Noitidart We don't use XUL any more, we use Add-on SDK.

Comment: Hi uri i dont know about chrome and safari. What do you mean about the xul? The link i shared is not an xul/overlay addon demo its a bootstrap demo which all sdk addons are based.

Comment: @Noitidart You use a function called `getXULWindowEnumerator`, isn't it a XUL function? I saw the term XUL many times in the source code. We are using Add-on SDK extensions, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons

Comment: You have to work with windows. All of Firefox is XUL. You can replace that function with getWindowEnumerator though which works with the DOMWindows instead of the XULWindows. The DOMWindows are the containers in XUL windows and is still XUL. You can't escape XUL.